# background-size min() min(); works in chrome but doesn't in firefox or Edge

Tags: css

I just started developing a new site and already ran into trouble with different browsers.

I have these lines of css to set the background image:

```
body
{
    background-image: url("../Images/Background.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: max(100vw, 1920px) max(100vh, 876px);

}
```

This works fine in Chrome, but doesn't apply the background size in Firefox or Edge.
In the Firefox inspector it says 'invalid property value'.

Do you have any work around? I want the image to stretch to the window size, but maintain its size at its resolution if the window is smaller. I can't use min-height as that would stretch the window even if there is no content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate this using pseudo element:

```css
html:before {
  content: "";
  position:fixed;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: url("https://i.picsum.photos/id/1074/800/800.jpg") center/cover no-repeat;
  min-width:800px;
  min-height:800px;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works on Firefox, Chrome, Edge and even internet explorer!